# How to execute a Ruby code from inside a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, operating-system, cloud, sandbox

I'm trying to execute a Ruby script file.
Assuming the input is a string that contains the file content.
What are the possible ways? taking into considerations that I need to keep the output of the executed file whether stdout or not separated from the Main script.

As an example of what I'm trying to do is have a function called `execute(code)`

Then calling `execute('4 + 5')` would return `9` although I can write a whole Ruby script in the place of `'4 + 5'`.

If anyone can forward me to any related tutorials or books, I'd be thankful :)

Comment: Do you think about something like [`eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval)? Are you aware of the security risks that come with tools like this?

Comment: is there a reason why `require` wouldn't work?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. that's why I'm trying to find something else other than eval.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can call shell commands in Ruby, it's as simple and intuitive as surrounding your desired command in backticks.

The output gets returned, so just save it to a variable:

script1.rb:

```
puts "asdf"
```

script2.rb:

```
output = `ruby script1.rb`    
puts output
```

```
"asdf"
```

---

I question what exactly it is you're trying to do, though. Because this is totally unintuitive and roundabout. Are you sure you aren't just looking for a module or something?

Comment: Actually I wanted to provide a way for others to run their code. Although I don't know yet how I'll sandbox the code running.